# Error of override Method

Tags: java, android

[Error at Override as shown in the image link. I have written this code in main activity of my program and it is showing an error at override of onsuccessListener and when i was running the whole code on android device monitor, the output displayed on android device was - APP has stopped][1]  Please someone help me out to solve this issue. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BztIM.jpg

```
private void accessGoogleFit() {
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();


Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
        .readData(readRequest)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess()");
          }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
          @Override
          public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure()", e);
          }
        })
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete()");
          }
        });
```

Comment: Please show your code as text and state clearly what error you get.

Comment: are you sure you are calling for `DataReadResponse` ??

Comment: hover over your **error** and check what it says

Comment: chamge `DataReadResponse` in `onSuccess` to `TResult tresult`

Comment: @luk2302 I kept my code please suggest me thank you.

Comment: @SantanuSur I tried your suggestion but still I am getting error. Can you  please suggest me in other way. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess()");
          }
        })
```

Comment: Happy to help :)